# Given $E[Y]=1$ , $E[Y^2]=2$ and $E[Y^3]=5$, Y non negative integer random variable, find min of $P[Y=0]$

Tags: probability

If $Y$ is a non negative integer-valued random variable with $E[Y]=1$, $E[Y^2]=2$ and $E[Y^3]=5$ ,where  $E$ is the average value of $Y$.
Find the minimum value of the possibility $P[Y=0]$.

I know that $E[Y]=\sum^{n}_{i=1}y_{i}p(y_{i})$ and $E[Y]=\sum_{y:p(y)>0}yp(y)$.

I know that Markov's inequality is : $P[Y\geq a]
\leq\frac{E[Y]}{a}$

I know that  Chebyshev's inequality is : $P(|Y-E[Y]|\geq k)\leq \frac{Var(Y)}{k^2}$

The book I'm studying is the : A first course in probability 8th edition , Sheldon Ross

Comment: I know what is the average of Y but I have no idea what is the connection between the average and the  min of P[Y=0]. Any ideas please ?

Comment: Here is an idea : first find out what goes wrong when $P[Y=0] = 0$. Think about the definitions, think about some inequalities you might know.

Comment: How do I connect the possibility of min P[Y=0] with E[Y],E[Y^2] and E[Y^3] ??Also which inequalities do you actually mean ? I dont get what's the problem with P[Y=0]=0 , could you be more specific please ?

Comment: Just to give you that mini-answer : if $P[Y= 0] =0$ then $P[Y \geq 1] = 1$, so  $E[Y] \geq 1$ as well as $Y$ can only take values bigger than $1$. But it is equal to $1$, which can happen only if $P[Y = 1] = 1$. But then $Y=1$ won't allow $E[Y^2] = 2$ , of course. If you understood this , then I can help you. But we need to reopen this question before we can work on it.

Comment: Yes i get what you say in the above comments , but what do you mean reopen the question ? I don't know what to do because  I'm new here . I really need your help ,so tell me what shall I do to reopen the question .

Comment: no it's right but the site does not let me publish my question because it does not follow up with the guidelines

Comment: yes sure , no problem .

Comment: the book is in greek and if i translate it ,it's called basic principles of possibilities theory

Comment: ok I edited my  question

Comment: thanks ,but when is it going to reopen ??

Comment: thanks, so i will just wait ?

Comment: FYI I am thinking about this problem too! I have $$P(Y=0)+\frac{3}{4}P(Y=1)\geq\frac{1}{2}$$ $$P(Y=0)+\frac{26}{27}P(Y=1)+\frac{19}{27}P(Y=2)\geq \frac{22}{27}$$ Once we find our candidate for the minimum value of $P(Y=0)$ we need show this minimum value is indeed attained.

Comment: @MatthewPilling I understand this : $$P(Y\geq 2)\leq \frac{E[Y]}{2}\Rightarrow 1-P(Y=0)-P(Y=1)\leq \frac{1}{2}$$ 
How do you find your first inequality ?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon  I think the question opened again .

Comment: Thank you very much for your help , I'm working on it too . Let's hope that we figure it out !

Comment: Using the fact that $$E(Y^2)=1^2P(Y=1)+2^2P(Y=2)+3^2P(Y=3)+\dots$$ we can deduce

\begin{eqnarray*}
2 & = & P(Y=1)+4P(Y=2)+9P(Y=3)+16P(Y=4)+\dots
\\ & \geq & P(Y=1)+4P(Y=2)+4P(Y=3)+4P(Y=4)+\dots \\
 & = & \big[P(Y=1)+P(Y=2)+\dots\big]+3\big[P(Y=2)+P(Y=3)+\dots\big] \\ & = & 1-P(Y=0)+3P(Y\geq 2) \\ & = & 1-P(Y=0)+3\big[1-P(Y=0)-P(Y=1)\big] \\ & = & 4-4P(Y=0)-3P(Y=1)
\end{eqnarray*} Rearranging terms gets your first inequality. A similar approach will also give you the second inequality. I'm not sure how much this will help you. I'll continue to think about it as well.

Comment: ok i understand thank you.so i suppose you do something like this to find the second ineqyality with $E[Y^3]$

Comment: @ThanasisZoumis I thought for some time, and I really cannot get the answer. Your question is so good! I wish I could give a +2, but I can't! Such a simple looking question, yet very very rewarding.I hope someone answers your question, I am giving up!

Comment: thanks you so much for your help and time !

Comment: @ThanasisZoumis Hey , welcome. Listen, if you ever need help on your questions, do approach me , either from this question, or my chatroom which is [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119549/teresa-lisbon-senior-agent-cbi). I will delete some comments I made here which are not required anymore. You can also visit the Constructive Feedback room [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback) , although we are still trying to activate it. I shall drink (juice) to your question being answered excellently, in the meantime.

Comment: ok ,thank you very much !!

Answer (score 9):

Let $f(Y) = (Y-1)(Y-2)(Y-3)$. Expectation $\mathbb E$ is linear so $$
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb E(f(Y)) &=& \mathbb E((Y-1)(Y-2)(Y-3)) \\
&=&\mathbb E(Y^3-6 Y^2 + 11 Y -6) \\ 
&=& 5 - 6 \cdot 2 + 11 - 6 \\ &=& -2
\end{eqnarray}$$
Denote $p_k= \mathbb P(Y=k)$.  Then another expression for the expectation is $$
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb E(f(Y)) &=& p_0 f(0) + p_1 f(1) + p_2 f(2) + p_3 f(3) + \ldots \\
&=& -6 p_0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + \textrm{ non-negative terms} \\
&\geq& -6 p_0
\end{eqnarray}$$
So $-2 = \mathbb E(f(Y)) \geq -6 p_0$, or $p_0 \geq \tfrac13$.

This bound is sharp since we can take $p_0=\tfrac13$, $p_1=\tfrac12$, $p_3=\tfrac16$, and all other probabilities zero to get the required expectations for $Y$, $Y^2$, and $Y^3$.

Comment: Great answer, +1. I think the idea of considering this polynomial to get the bound was phenomenal, and I will try it in the future with similar questions.

Comment: Thank you very much , but I have a question :
If I take $f(Y)=(Y-1)(Y-4)(Y-5)=Y^3-10Y^2+29Y-20$

Comment: Thank you very much , but I have a question :
If I take $$f(Y)=(Y-1)(Y-4)(Y-5)=Y^3-10Y^2+29Y-20$$
Then $$E(f(Y))=5-10\cdot 2+29-20=-6$$
So $-6=E(f(Y))\geq -20p_{0}+ 0+f(2)p_{2}+f(3)p_{3}+0+0+f(6)p_{6}+\cdots$
So $$-6\geq -20 p_{0} \Rightarrow p_{0}\geq \frac{3}{10}$$

Because $f(2)>0,f(3)>0,f(x)>0, \forall x>5$

So the question is why i found a different min than yours , shouldn't it be unique? Do I miss something in your solution ?

Comment: Well, $\tfrac3{10}< \tfrac13$, so your bound is just not the best possible. Equality in your case would require that only $p_0, p_1, p_4, p_5$ are non-zero and $p_0=\tfrac3{10}$,  but no such choice can meet the required expectations.

Comment: sorry but can you explain me how do you choose your polymomial to have the expectations.You begin from the expectations to find your polynomial?First you solve the system and then you construct it?

Comment: My guess was that the best option would be to only allow the first four probabilities to be non-zero. That turned out to give a solution right away.

Comment: i understand that by solving the system you find po=1/3,p1=1/2,p2=0 ,p3=1/6 but i have not understand yet the connection between them and the polynomial.sorry dut can you explain to me in detail how you find your polynomial please?Thank you.