# Find the minimun value of $P(X=0)$ for non negative integer values of $X$.

Tags: probability

Consider a non-negative integer random variable $X$ which satisfies $\mathbb{E}[X]=1, \mathbb{E}[X^2]=2, \mathbb{E}[X^3]=5$.

Find the minimun value of $P(X=0)$.

I managed to show that $$Var(X) = \mathbb{E}[X^2]-\mathbb{E}[X]^2=2-1=1$$
but then I'm stuck. Any hint?

Comment: What is $p(0)$?

Comment: i edited. it is p(x=0)

Comment: Look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4077513/given-ey-1-ey2-2-and-ey3-5-y-non-negative-integer-random-variab